# Is cudamallocmanaged smart enough to not copy data which is not needed?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

The doubt I have about cudamallocmanaged is that if I malloc N numbers, after GPU finish a operation on those numbers(let say a scan operation), I only need the last number in the array and access only this number in the host. Will cudamallocmanaged only copy this number back?

I did a test and my answer is no. So I think in this case cudamalloc/free/copy is faster than cudamallocmanaged. Correct me if I am wrong.

Then this following question is: How does it work to know when and how much to copy back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is generally Yes, on a page (usually 4K) basis.  For CPU->GPU copies, the driver copies CPU pages lazily by tracking dirty bits.  After a kernel launch, the managed memory is marked nonresident so CPU accesses will fault.  Then after a CPU/GPU sync operation, it is left nonresident and the driver resolves page faults by copying the accessed page back from device memory.

This is based on a study I did sometime last year, so it may have changed since then.  Given the semantics of managed memory, NVIDIA has many different implementation options and you can expect them to change as NVIDIA optimizes their code.

I measured block GPU->CPU copies of managed memory at 500MB/s, 25x slower than a pinned memcpy would be, so expect changes as NVIDIA figures out how to optimize those code paths.  For example, if they do dirty bit tracking on the GPU side, they could speculatively copy pages written by the GPU back to CPU memory.  That would deliver higher bandwidth, but could cause superfluous copies of data that is never accessed.

Comment: So the granularity so far is in page basis(4k) right? if I only want to copy 4 bytes, it will still copy redundant data?

Comment: Yes, there are two issues in play. One is that the hardware really does not support tracking memory accesses that are finer-grained than a page. The other is that even for a 4K page (as opposed to say 4 bytes), the system spends a miniscule amount of time copying data as opposed to in other overhead operations. For example, for small copies, it often takes the driver longer to compose the hardware commands to do the copy than it takes the hardware to copy the data.